# Double-dabble algorithm for IEEE754

Tags: algorithms

The [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble) explanation is clear to convert unsigned integer binary format into `Binary Coded Decimal`.

The double-dabble algorithm is trying separate binary digit to BCD for example:
Given 4-bit input `1101` (13 in decimal) will produce `0001 0011`

The input from example clearly is unsigned integer, but how about IEEE754 representation which using floating point instead of unsigned integer?

I expect the algorithm is like this:

given single precission input (32-bit) using IEEE754 format.

```
sign (1-bit) | exponent (8-bit) | mantissa (23-bit)
```

Input:

```
(this IEEE 754 representation is 0.3 in decimal)
0 | 01111101 | 00110011001100110011001
```

note: `|` just for separating so it will easier to read.

will produce BCD output of 0.3:

```
0000 1111 0011
```

where:

- 0000 is 0 in decimal
- 1111 (yes there's no 1111 in BCD so i will use it as dot point to represent comma)
- 0011 is 3 in decimal

note: No need follow what I expect, feel free to suggest me if there's other way to display float decimal from IEEE 754.

Comment: I have edited my Question

Comment: The simplest possible way would be `bytes(bcd[c] for c in str(f)[:max_digits])` where `bcd` is a map of digits to BCD encodings.